# Use jQuery clone to copy only 1 row with classname

Tags: jquery, html, clone

I've been struggling with this for two days! From a suggestion in SO, I put the add button in the table footer. When it's clicked for the first time, it adds one new row, which is what I want. The second time, however, it adds two new rows; the third time, four new rows; the fourth time, eight new rows! It gets worse and worse!

This code is for adding members to a database. The first row is the member's own information. The other rows are for the user to add other members to their group. So it's the second or later rows that I want to clone. The new rows should be added at the end.

The tr to be copied has a class of .leaderrow. I think the jQuery is copying all of the rows with that class each time, instead of just one. How can I get it to add just the one row each time the button is clicked?

Here's the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addRow').live('click', function() {
        $('.leaderrow').clone().appendTo('#entries');
    });
})
```

Here's the table, which is part of a form:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" class="unsorted_table">
  <thead>   
      <tr>
           <th>Name*</th>
           <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="entries">
      <tr>
            <td>User's own name</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="leaderrow">
            <td><select name="leaderid[]" >
              <option value="3">Sue</option>
              <option value="4">Jeannie</option>
              <option value="5">Kerry</option>
              <option value="6">Travis</option>
               </select>
            </td>
            <td><a href="" name="delete_row[]" class="remove">remove</a></td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
       <tr> 
            <td><p><input type="button" id="addRow" value="Add Another" /></p></td>
       </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `$('.leaderrow')` selects all elements that match that class.  You could use [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first), [`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last) or [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq) to select a specific one.

I however would suggest that you add a HIDDEN `.leaderrow.template` (has both classes) that is cloned, then [`.removeClass('templaterow')`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass) before appending.

Also, if you are dealing with more than one table, you might want to do something with [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to restrict the area you are searching:

```
var tmpl = $(this).closest('table').find('.leaderrow.template');
tmpl.clone().removeClass('template').insertBefore(tmpl);
// and use CSS:
// .leaderrow.template { display: none; }
```

Comment: Everytime he clones he's getting more results from the `$('.leaderrow')` than before.  I like the `.first()` solution personally.

Comment: SO is fantastic! While I was editing the two of you answered by question with really useful information.

Comment: .first worked perfectly, since it doesn't matter for this purpose which row is cloned.

    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#addRow').live('click', function() {
      $('.leaderrow').first().clone().appendTo('#entries');
     });
    })

Comment: I have a few more pages where I will have more than one table so .closest will be very useful. Thanks for the great advice gnarf and tjameson!